# Sending email via c# goes to spam

Tags: c#, sendmail

I use the method to send email:

```
    public void Enviar(MailAddress from, MailPriority prioridade)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(new PartnerDB().ParServidorSMTP);
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = from;
        mail.Subject = this.Assunto;
        mail.Priority = prioridade;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = this.Conteudo;

        foreach (var email in this.Para) mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        foreach (var email in this.Copia) mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        foreach (var email in this.CopiaOculta) mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        foreach (var anexo in this.CaminhoAnexos) mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(anexo));
        foreach (var anexo in this.StreamAnexos) mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(anexo.StreamBytes, anexo.MimeType));

        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Instancia.LogError(new SiteSession().User.Login, "SendMail.Enviar", ex, this.Assunto);
        }

        mail.Dispose();
    }
```

Calling the method changing the email address and with one it goes to spam, with other not, like exempla below:

```
            {
                string corpo = "Testing email via C#";
                var mail = new SendMail("eduardo.chafick@hotmail.com", "subject testing via c# eduardo", corpo);
                mail.Enviar(new MailAddress("xxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com"), MailPriority.High);
            }

            {
                string corpo = "Testing email via C#";
                var mail = new SendMail("eduardo.chafick@hotmail.com", "subject testing via c# leanndro", corpo);
                mail.Enviar(new MailAddress("yyyyyyy@yyyyyyyyy.com"), MailPriority.High);
            }
```

when I use the MailAddress (from) as 'eduardo.chafick@hotmail.com' the email goes to Spam, but when I use 'leandro@xxxxx.com' it goes to correct inbox (not to spam), Someone Knows tell me why???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your mail server isn't allowed to send emails from Hotmail.

Comment: if you see an email from "xxx" won't you open it??? :P anyway, it is because of the clients' rules... it has nothing to do with u're code. The combination of the sender with the subject might cause this to be considered as spam)

Comment: Your email is being sent with the name of your email, but not from the hotmail servers, which makes it appear "fake".

Answer (score 0):

Mail servers have a lot of rules to fight/detect spam - so you are hitting one or more rules.

Getting mail from [open mail relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay) (which is what you doing when mail address does not match server the mail come from) is pretty good indication of spam.